# how do i check for newline or the beginning of line in file using VB

Tags: vb.net

I have to read an image file and i have to encode and compress that image in order to that I want to track each line of the file which i want to compress.How do I do that, help me out if you better options also you are most welcome to share them.
 I am reading image file , storing lines into buffer which I want to compress.

Comment: A couple of questions: first of all, what have you tried so far?  It's always best if you should some effort before just asking other people to do it for you.  Secondly, you say "image", do you mean a picture, or a file containing a memory or disk snapshot?  Either way they're going to be binary files, so "lines" is probably not the concept you're looking for.  There's a fundamental difference between binary and ASCII files.

Comment: @adrain thank you so much. I have tried to google out.. but I asked question if I can get better option.This is small part where I'm stuck .Its an BMP image which I have read and converted its decimal values into hex.Now in order to compress image I had to track lines.

Comment: There are a number of readily available compression libraries.  Is there a reason you need to roll your own?

Comment: Anyways thank you people I got it..

Answer (score 0):

Use vbCrLf

It may also be that you have only line feeds or only carrige returns so using Chr(10) and Chr(13) may also be a better option.